# Why can't Microsoft teams see my camera's content on my Samsung Galaxy S9?

Tags: camera, microsoft-teams

Microsoft Teams does have access to the camera:

[image]

But Microsoft Teams doesn't see anything on my camera:

[image]

Why can't Microsoft teams see my camera's content on my Samsung Galaxy S9?

My default camera can see my two cameras' content without any issue.

Switching between the two cameras didn't help. The two cameras have the same issue in Teams.

Rebooting the phone didn't help.

Comment: Do you have some permissions Manager installed, such as some appops app or XprivacyLua? Those apps might  be autoconfigured to deny camera access to apps until explicitly allowed by the user. Otherwise, have you tried clearing data of Teams app? Is this a sudden problem or has Teams never been able to access Camera since its installation? Since when did the problem start? Any update to system or Teams app after which you observed this problem?

Comment: Can other apps (other than the default camera and Microsoft Teams) use the camera?